# Why am I getting an error for a REST Invocation in Powershell to clone a Git repo?

Tags: git, powershell

I'm getting an error kickback when attempting to run the below Powershell script:

```
PS C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop> C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\git_cloner.ps1
Enter the name of the directory to save all project files: : default
Provide the list of GitHub URLs to pull: : url.txt
Provide Git release branch to target: : <redcated>
Provide the GitHub token to use: : <redacted>
...

url.txt
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}
At C:\Users\<redacted>\Desktop\git_cloner.ps1:5 char:17
+     $repoInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) 
[Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Full code:

```
# Function to clone a repository using GitHub API 
function CloneGitHubRepo($repoName, $accessToken, $repoBranch, $cloneDirectory) { 
    $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken" } 
    $url = "https://api.github.com/repos/$repoName" 
    $repoInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers 
    
    if ($repoInfo) { 
        $cloneUrl = $repoInfo.clone_url 
        git clone $cloneUrl -b $repoBranch $cloneDirectory --progress -v
    } 
    else { 
        Write-Host "Failed to retrieve repository information for $repoName" 
    } 
} 

#Prompt user /for a home directory to make
$save_directory = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the directory to save all project files: "

#Prompt user for file containing list of GitHub repository URLs
$git_list = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide the list of GitHub URLs to pull: "

#Prompt user for GitHub Release Branch to target
$git_branch = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide Git release branch to target: "

#Prompt user for GitHub API Token
$git_token = Read-Host -Prompt "Provide the GitHub token to use: "

#Create Save Directory
If(!(test-path -PathType container $save_directory))
{
      New-Item -Path $save_directory -ItemType Directory
}

# Loop through each repository and clone it 
foreach ($git_uri in $git_list) {
    Write-Host $git_uri
    CloneGitHubRepo $git_uri $git_token $git_branch $save_directory
}
```

For some reason Powershell doesn't like my RestMethod Invocation? Would native curl commands be the better option? Any ideas where I'm running afoul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the string value `url.txt` as the repo name, so you end up hitting `https://api.github.com/repos/url.txt`, which is why you receive a "Not Found" error.

Make sure you actually read the contents of the file path given by the user:

```
# Use Get-Content to read the contents of the file
# Loop through each repository and clone it 
foreach ($git_uri in Get-Content -Path $git_list) {
    Write-Host $git_uri
    CloneGitHubRepo $git_uri $git_token $git_branch $save_directory
}
```

The API endpoint you're targeting has the format `/repos/<owner>/<name>/...`, so you'll need to ensure the contents of `url.txt` contains exactly that, eg.:

```
PowerShell/PowerShell
murkywaters/SuperApp
someOtherUser/AnotherRepo
...
```